# Datetime returns wrong time in unix

Tags: python, datetime

I have a wired situation here with returning the time in unix format.

I have this function:

```
def get_today_date():
   nowDate = str(datetime.datetime.utcnow().date())
   unix_date = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(nowDate, "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple())
   return (unix_date)
```

it's straightforward when I print the value of "nowDate" -> it gives me the right value I want (ex: 7/29/2018 00:00:00 UTC) which is correct. But when I change the format from Unix timestamp to date format and get only the date without time, It gives me (7/28/2018).

I've took the value in unix and checked it, it gives me (7/28/2018 21:00:00). Why?

My laptop is in a UTC +3 timezone.

Did something go wrong in the conversion? Or its an internal error in my laptop makes the output wrong?

Comment: Some of the data time functions take timezone into account and some don't. This is where you probably made a mistake, but it is not clear what exactly you did, because you say that `nowDate` is `'7/29/2018 00:00:00 UTC'`, but that cannot  be, because it is a date string, e.g. `'2018-07-29'`. You also say that `unix_date` is `7/28/2018 21:00:00`, but that also cannot be, because it is just a number, e.g. `1532815200.0`. So, please show the exact code you run which gives you the wrong result, so we can tell you exactly what you did wrong.

Comment: BTW, to get today's date, you only need to call `datetime.date.today()`.

Comment: @zvone I need to get the date + time(which always will be 00:00:00) to get the midnight time of each day in unix timestamp because I have records I need to check their status and this time makes the process easier in terms of returned rows. `datetime.date.today` returns the date in readable format. I need it in unix

Comment: So, you need the unix timestamp of the midnight of the current day. OK. But "midnight of the current day" is ambiguous. In my time zone, that would now be Sunday midnight, which was 10 hours ago in my timezone, but in Hawaii that would be a Saturday midnight, which was 22 hours ago in their timezone. So, (**first question**) which midnight do you want? Yours? GMT? Something else? And, (**second question**) when you _"took the value in unix and checked it"_, which time zone did you use to check it? Maybe you made a mistake there?

Comment: 1,2) I need it in UTC timezone because I store all the values in UTC and I take the user's timezone (from DB) to convert it to them in their time zone. So, in this case, nothing should affect their experience.
I'll compare from the midnight in UTC for today till the next midnight (I'll add total number of seconds in the day).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for today's date/time, use `datetime.datetime.now()`, if you need just the date, use `datetime.datetime.today()` it's automatically converted into your timezone.

If you play with `UTC`-based functions, you'll get 3 hours offset for your location, which sometimes might result in time being 21:00 of previous day instead of midnight of the next one -- that's quite reasonable =)

---

you may use the following approach:

```
utcnow = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
midnight = time.mktime( datetime.datetime( utcnow.year, utcnow.month, utcnow.day).timetuple() )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I need is the midnight of each day in unix. I have thousands of records and this will sort the records. Is there any ready function to return midnight in unix timestamp?

Comment: @MohamedL do you need midnight in your time zone or UTC midnight?

Comment: UTC midnight. because I have different time zones and I'm centralizing the processes in UTC

Comment: The same thing, it returns 28/7/2018 21:00:00. the first line returns the correct date and time in Unix. Something wrong with `time.mktime()`